# How do I run the install.sh file for this wi-fi adapter? I get "su: Authentication failure"

Tags: drivers, executable, su

I have got a 600m wireless-n mini USB adapter from Realtek, model number OT-wua600nm.

I'm trying to install through drive. I copy the file (linux) and paste into desktop and change the permissions and opened `install.sh` in terminal. I am asked for my password and I type it, but I get this error:

```
su: Authentication failure
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
Password:
```

How can I install the wi-fi adapter?

Comment: Try to provide full permission and check it again.

Comment: will you explain how to change that?

Comment: using chmod command provide full permission. ex:- chmod 644 file.htm

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal in root mode and navigate to the directory that contains `install.sh` using `cd` and type:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

That's it.

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this to clarify what you mean by "in root mode" (or to remove that wording if it's not important)? The point of `sudo` is usually that you're not running as root but want to run a command as root. I strongly suspect that just opening a regular terminal but otherwise following the directions in this answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

To open in root mode enter this command:

```bsh
sudo -i
```

And enter password.

Comment: Possible but dangerous. Using sudo is the preferred way.